# Confusing about the function(data) format in some longer html code

Tags: javascript, ajax

```html
  var fileExt = {};
  fileExt[0]=".md";
  $.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: "./post/",
    success: function(data) {
       $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
        console.log(data);
       //List all markdown file names in the page
       $(data).find("a:contains('.md')").each(function () {
           console.log(this.href);
           var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
           $("#fileNames").append( '<li>'+filename+'</li>');
       });
       $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
     }     
  });
```

I check the code reading on my 'post' folder file list, now seems the output on part of the *.md file is not get the fully name like using ajax to transfer and seems some of the charactors lost. like here Test_Some_MarkDown_Code.md change to Test_Some_MarkDown_C..> but the another file C-2.md is ok.

any length limit for the ajax?  what's the root cause?

```html
    <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="C-2.md">C-2.md</a>                 </td><td align="right">23-ʮ����-2016 19:33  </td><td align="right">5.2K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="Test_Some_MarkDown_Code.md">Test_Some_MarkDown_C..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">23-ʮ����-2016 19:30  </td><td align="right">2.2K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Comment: Please tell me what you think `$(HTMLEscape(data))` does?

Comment: Thanks Ed, sorry, this is typo which I am trying to use the html code to replace the ..&gt.

Comment: Issue happened at console.log(data);

Comment: Pray tell - what is the issue

Comment: I using  console.log(data) to print in console and press F12 to checking the ajax data in firefox 50.1.0 , now I found the data variable showing me most of the html code on the file name is correct, like C-2.md, only this file Test_Some_MarkDown_Code.md which seems longer on name, the content between <a> and </a> is not fully output as a <a href="Test_Some_MarkDown_Code.md">Test_Some_MarkDown_C..&gt;</a> instead of normal html code like C-2.md: <a href="C-2.md">C-2.md</a>

Comment: I have some more context. I encouraged the author to post here after asking in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325912. He is using XAMPP / Apache as the local server.

The text `Test_Some_MarkDown_C..&gt;` is valid HTML, and `&gt;` is the HTML entity for `>`, the "greater than" sign. This is being done by the Apache web server, not by jQuery's ``ajax()``. 20 bytes is the default [NameWidth option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions.namewidth) for mod_autoindex.

It seems you want the full filename, which is there as the ``href`` attribute.

Comment: Great debug, John. yes, it should be a Apache setup issue,and I will try to setup my local server setting on the NameWidth to fix it. will post my solution later.

Comment: Fix the issue by adding following code in httpd.conf under apache\conf\ and restart the Apache server.

<Directory />
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
IndexOptions NameWidth=30 DescriptionWidth=450 IconHeight=16 IconWidth=16 FoldersFirst
</Directory>

Again, thanks to John and Ed's great support! Happy new year. :-)